# how do I center the content of s router-outlet

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to horizontally center the content of a router-outlet in angular; However all the regular tricks I am using are not working; after searching google for all the usual suspects
i tried:

- display: block; margin: 0 auto;
- placing it in a div and using the above code
- trying to select the component that will be there depending on the route even though may or may not be there
- I can center it by adding padding to the body but it will then not be centered on all screen sizes
- I centered a img above the component just to see if display: block; margin: 0 auto; works at all, it works on the img tag
- used the depricated 'center' tag
- used text-align: center;

this is an angular 2+ project

html:

```
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/6R6pcMm/MRG-Updated-Logo.jpg" />   <!--centered-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>                               <!--not_centered-->
```

css:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

router-outlet {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="center-me"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

CSS

```
.center-me{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel dumb the answer was to do this AND combine it with 'text-align:center;'